# Windows/NetBeans platform - Getting JAVA_HOME environment variable into conf file

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, environment-variables, configuration-files

I'm trying to use the JAVA_HOME windows environment variable as the jdkhome directory in a netbeans platform application. The variable is definitely set (it was originally a user variable, but I added an environment variable as well because I thought that might be the issue). My config file currently contains the line

jdkhome="${JAVA_HOME}"

I tried

jdkhome=${JAVA_HOME}

as well. Neither of these work - it says there is no valid java install. It does work if I manually write out the directory that JAVA_HOME points to.

I've tried asking on the official netbeans forum, but there hasn't been any response.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `%JAVA_HOME%` and see if that works.

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work either. still tells me there's no valid java install there.

Comment: Odd. I'm betting you've done the same google surfing, and the closest I've seen to something that looks vaguely like what you want is http://forums.netbeans.org/ntopic20498.html, which seems to imply you can't use environment variables in the way you want. Sorry, but not sure you have too many options there.

Comment: Yeah, saw that topic as well. I guess I'll have to find another way to do it! Thanks anyway.